# Making the member of a structure of type structure double pointer

Tags: c

Suppose I have a structure named 'Item'. I have to make a member of Item double pointer inside another structre.

```
struct Item{
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
};

struct Inventory{
    struct Item double* item;
    int NUMITEMS;
};
```

Comment: I don't think so,type of Item double pointer is not valid

Comment: @klutt It didn't work.Is there any other method to do so?

Comment: It does not make any sense. Would you try to declare someting like `int double var;`? Why have you written `double` after `Item`?

Comment: Often, when people refer to a "double" pointer, what they mean is something like `int **ptr;`. That's not the same as a pointer to double, which would be something like `double *ptr;`

Comment: @user3386109 Now I understood :D

Comment: @user3386109 Do you want to write an answer or should I?

Comment: @klutt Go for it. It's not clear to me what the OP is actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user3386109 Hmmm, you're right. This question is not clear enough.

Comment: @IcanCode You should [edit] your question to make it clearer. I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Try to create a [mre]. I'm voting to close this question meanwhile.

Comment: It's my fault @klutt my question in assignment was telling item double pointer and i misunderstood it as a struct item double* item

Comment: @IcanCode Update your question with the assignment text, and I'll write an answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the term *double pointer* is ambiguous. It can mean two different things:

1. Pointer to double `double *ptr;`
2. Pointer to pointer `T **ptr;` where `T` is any type. It could be `double` :)

Which of these is depending on context.

So in your case, do this:

```
struct Inventory{
    struct Item **item;
    int NUMITEMS;
};
```

Accessing these is not that tricky. You could do something like this:

```
struct Inventory inventory;
// Do something
struct Item *item = inventory.item[index];
struct Item item2 = *(inventory.item[index]);
```

Comment: @IcanCode Please don't change code in that way. It invalidates existing answers. I edited a line back.